# Android how to use dialogfragment effecitively(using multiple dialog)

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I want to show many dialogs in one activity.
I can show one dialog now, but when I add more dialog, it confuses me.
Here is my code.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //then create a alertDialog class
    String [] age = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.age);
    String [] job = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.job);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("당신의 나이는?");
    builder.setItems(age, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((SetUpActivity)getActivity()).textView_age.setText(age[which]);
        }
    });

    builder.setTitle("당신의 직업은?");
    builder.setItems(job, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((SetUpActivity)getActivity()).textView_job.setText(job[which]);
        }
    });


    return builder.create();
}
```

When the user click the button,(and appear dialog box)
Here is a code

```
new FragmentDialogBox().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
```

Maybe I change the tag - "fragmentDialog" part?